# Unable to compile using MSTest.TestAdapter and MSTest.Testframework packages

Tags: msbuild, .net-core, nuget

I am looking to upgrade some of our test projects to MSBuild SDK format. Added reference to Nuget packages MSTest.TestAdapter and MSTest.TestFramework. when I try to compile, I get the following error

> C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(198,5):
>   error NU5100: The assembly
>   'content\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll'
>   is not inside the 'lib' folder and hence it won't be added as a
>   reference when the package is installed into a project. Move it into
>   the 'lib' folder if it needs to be referenced.

EDIT:
This only started happening once I updated to the latest .Net core on my machine. With an earlier verison (2.1.104), this was only shown as warning

> C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.104\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(194,5):
>   warning : Description: The assembly
>   'contentFiles\any\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll'
>   is not inside the 'lib' folder and hence it won't be added as
>   reference when the package is installed into a project.

Any ideas on how to resolve it?

Comment: Did you try adding NU5100 to the ignored warning list? Also do you need to pack the projects? If they are test projects I am wondering why they are creating a NuGet package since the pack target seems to be being called.

Comment: We could ignore it when it was a warning. It's showing as an error now.

Comment: Did you try adding it to the ignored warning list? Or is treat warnings as errors set to true in your project? Or it might be a change in a more recent version of NuGet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by setting the ExcludeAssets property for MSTest.TestAdapter to true. This is how my project file looked like in the end

```
<PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="1.2.1">
  <ExcludeAssets>all</ExcludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```